# Which preposition should be used in "married _______ the week after Easter": on, at or in?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I came across this sentence, where a student has to insert a correct preposition.

> For each sentence, fill in the blank with either *on,* *at*, or *in*.
>
> They got married _______ the week after Easter.

The answers say *in* is correct, but I feel a little confused. Is the book right?

Comment: 'They married the week after Easter.'

Comment: Many (most?) native speakers of  American English would use no  preposition there: *They got married the week after Easter*.

Answer (score 3):

The correct word is "during", or no preposition at all. Given those choices, "in" is best.

Answer (score 1):

If they got married on a specific date, then use **on**.
If they got married at a specific time, then use **at**.
If they got married within a specific time period, then use **in** or **during** or **within**.
If they got married at a specific venue, then use **at**.

Comment: @AndyT GOOD POINT....................I agree

Answer (score 1):

When we say last, next, every, this we do not also use *at*, *in*, *on*.

- I went to London last June. (not in last June)
- He's coming back next Tuesday. (not on next Tuesday)
- I go home every Easter. (not at every Easter)
- We'll call you this evening. (not in this evening)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the Grammar-Test, which includes the question mentioned here:
https://www.englishgrammar.org/prepositions-time-2/

I would also use "in" just to save a point on an examination test :-)

The two other possible answers given (on and at) would be wrong.